# What is the expire-groups-on-timeout equivalent in Java Config?

Tags: spring, spring-integration

As per the docs for expire-groups-on-timeout :
"When a group is completed due to a timeout (or by a MessageGroupStoreReaper), the group is expired (completely removed) by default. Late arriving messages will start a new group. Set this to false to complete the group but have its metadata remain so that late arriving messages will be discarded. Empty groups can be expired later using a MessageGroupStoreReaper together with the empty-group-min-timeout attribute. Default: 'true'."

How do I achieve that in with Java Config? Basically after a group times out, I want the late arriving messages to be discarded and also the group to be expired once all the messages have arrived so that it doesnt produce a memory leak. For the later part, I guess having the MessageGroupStoreReaper will work.

Answer (score 0):

In general, hyphenated properties are converted to camelCase, so

```
ab-cd-ef
```

is generally a property

```
abCdEf
```

However, there's a typo in the reference manual, it's `expire-groups-upon-timeout` not `expire-groups-on-timeout`.

So, you need `setExpireGroupsUponTimeout()`.

> I want the late arriving messages to be discarded and also the group to be expired once all the messages have arrived so that it doesnt produce a memory leak.

`expireGroupsUponCompletion` will remove the metadata for a complete group. To discard late messages after a timeout, but also clean up at some time later, you need a reaper and an appropriate setting in `setMinimumTimeoutForEmptyGroups()`.

Comment: Thanks for the response Gary. So if I understand correctly, I should set the setExpireGroupsUponTimeout(false) so that the group completes but does not expire and so the metadata remains and late arriving messages will not start a new group and will get discarded. And will need to add a reaper to remove these groups with the minTimeoutForEmptyGroups() settings. Is that the correct understanding?

Comment: If I set the expireGroupsUponTimeout to true, then late arriving messages will start a new group, but that group will also timeout after the group timeout value and it will be expired, right? At that time, the messages will be discarded. So looks like if my aggregation logic is to do something only if all messages arrive, else error out on timeout, then I dont need to worry about late arriving messages and dont need to have the reaper since the new group that they start will be expired on the next timeout. Is my understanding correct? Or do I need to worry about the late arriving messages?

Comment: Your understanding is correct; you only really need a reaper if (a) you wish to immediately discard late messages or (b) you want partial groups to complete "normally" on timeout.